How to integrate xmonad with systemd's graphical-session.target?
I wanted to take advantage of using systemd user services. But I realized that xmonad (which I'm using together with lightdm) doesn't seem to integrate with with it.
Apparently ligthdm shouldn't be responsible for that: https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/issues/29
I tried to search for an xmonad session systemd target/service/unit, but with no luck.
I also tried a brute-force hack, just as an expriment, to change my xmonad config to
main = bracket_
  (callCommand "systemctl start --user graphical-session-pre.target ; systemctl start --user graphical-session.target; true")
  (callCommand "systemctl stop  --user graphical-session.target ; systemctl stop  --user graphical-session-pre.target; true")
  (xmobar (ewmh myConfig) >>= xmonad) 

This didn't even start the session.
I guess the correct approach would be to create a systemd service unit for xmonad and let lightdm start it instead, but haven't managed that.
